# Validate .sh files header

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, linux-mint

How do i validate every .sh file in a specified directory which ends .sh to make sure the first line is #!/bin/bash?

I want the output for each file to be either `filename.sh is valid` or `filename.sh is missing the header`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider also pure-bash solution. It does not call any other process.

Note that a valid file may contain spaces between the `#!` and the `/bin/bash`.

```
#! /bin/bash
PAT="^#! */bin/bash"
for file in *.sh ; do
    line=
    read line < $file
    if [[ "$line" =~ $PAT ]] ; then
        echo "$file is valid"
    else
        echo "$file is missing the header"
    fi
done
```

If you need to support other interpreters (e.g., bin/sh), you can expand the pattern to include other shells with

```
PAT="#! *(/bin/bash|/bin/sh)"
```

Comment: Thank you this helped

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```sh
awk 'FNR == 1 { if ($0 == "#!/bin/bash") {
                   print FILENAME, "is valid"
                } else {
                   print FILENAME, "is missing the header"
                }
                nextfile
     }' *.sh
```